# Use VBA to switch dictionaries when using spell check (MS Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, spell-checking

I have this VBA function: when I exit a field, it launches the spell checker automatically. However I have fields in English and others in French, so I am looking for a way to set the Dictionnary language for each field so that Access knows which dictionnary/grammar checker to use.

So for instance how would you include the French language in this code?

```
Private Sub Field_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
       Dim strSpell
       strSpell = Field
       If IsNull(Len(strSpell)) Or Len(strSpell) = 0 Then
          Exit Sub
       End If
       With Field
           .SetFocus
           .SelStart = 0
           .SelLength = Len(strSpell)
       End With
       DoCmd.SetWarnings False
       DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling
       DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Trawling the internet came up with this:

```
Application.SetOption "Spelling dictionary language", xxxx
```

where xxxx is one of the constants listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432635%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Should be able to flip the switch back and forth when you need to.

Comment: I can't manage to make it work, where should I insert your code into mine? I tried between the first and second line without any success, and other places without success. Did you tried it?  Application.SetOption "Spelling dictionary language", msoLanguageIDFrench

Comment: Did you look at the list of languages? First, msoLanguageIDBasque is not a valid lanugage.  Second, enter the number, not the contstant integer constant and not the constant name as Access does not recognize it.  As far as where to put it, it's up to your application but somewhere before DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSpelling.  I have tried it and it works as far as changing the dictionary, yes.

Comment: ^ I meant msoLanguageIDFrench is not a valid language, sorry.  Copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this.

The dictionary is specified in a Windows setting.  I can imagine an API method to change this, but the closest thing I find is [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223822(v=office.11).aspx) about `.CheckSpelling` (which lets you specify an alternate dictionary when the specified one provides no match).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is about Access, but for future reference for Excel users, you can actually change the language settings using VBA. Examples shown below:

```
Application.SpellingOptions.DictLang = msoLanguageIDEnglishCanadian
Application.SpellingOptions.DictLang = msoLanguageIDFrenchCanadian
```